# How to remove auto correction in ngx date picker?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-datepicker in my application and there I'm using 'DD.MM.YYYY' as my dateInputFormat in the configuration of the date picker. Here my problem is
when I type a date manually adhering to the format 'YYYY.MM.DD', that typed value is changed to 'DD.MM.YYYY'. Not only the format, but also the input date value. For an instance if I enter 2019.04.25, it will be changed to 20.04.2025 instead of showing invalid date. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config parameters something like this:

```
[bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY.MM.DD'}"
```

Check the docs for details [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#config-object).

Comment: I'm using dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY'. My problem is when I'm typing manually in YYYY.MM.DD format it's auto corrected  instead of showing invalid date. Any idea?